# Android App to show the information about which app used how much time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I'm looking to develop an application to show the information of all the other apps installed on the phone and how much time they are used.

what I want to know is,

Is it possible to do such kind of app on Android?

Android will run the apps in background even if there is no user interaction with it, Can we get the time only user interacted with the app?

Please help me with this..

Thanks in Advance.

Harry

Comment: cool idea for an app if it can be done.

Comment: I think this is a pretty serious privacy violation, I'm not sure that this information would be available.

Comment: Thanks Ben. @ Tim : I don't think it is , there some apps like these to show phone usage.

Comment: @matheszabi : could you please explain why it can't ?

Comment: @harry it is possible and I told in my answer, which it was down voted and no up votes. It seems (again) the finish appreciated only, not the fishing knowledge.

Comment: @matheszabi: sorry, I haven't seen your answer. But, I'm happy that it is possible to do. Do you know any samples of these kind of apps to your knowledge ?

Answer (score 0):

The SpareParts app can do it. Luckily, SpareParts is a part of the Android OS and is Open Source. 
Try to get some hints in the code.

Source code is avalaible here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/SpareParts/

Clone the source with `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/SpareParts` to your computer.